# Link to position on web page using class

Tags: css, html, scroll, hyperlink

I know that I can link to a position on a webpage by using an id. But is it possible for me to do that using a class.

With an id it looks like this: `href=#id`. First you put the #, which is the id selector, and then the id.

This works out very nice with id's because there's only one on a page. But there are usually multiple instances of a class, so in javascript to specify a single one you do class[index].

With this in mind, I would assume that to link to classes I would do this: `href=.class[index]`. The `.` is the class selector, and [index] is to specify which class I'm pointing to.

This obviously doesn't work (why else am I asking the community), so what I'm asking, in short, is: How do I get a link within a webpage that only has a class as a selector.

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking for simply cannot be done.

The difference between IDs and classes is that IDs **have** to be unique, whereas classes don't. Because of this, a '[**jumplink**](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479511)' cannot know which element you're intending to jump to. While it might make sense to simply jump to the first class present, this is not how jumplinks operate.

However, the same functionality **can** be achieved with JavaScript's **[`.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)** method:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("top")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
    window.scrollTo(0, document.querySelector(".bottom").offsetTop);
});
```

```css
.bottom {
  margin-top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">Top - Click Me!</div>
<div class="bottom">Bottom</div>
```

Comment: This does seem pretty useful. But the point of doing it with the regular link method is to be able to make a URL that takes me to a point in a page on a website that I don't own. Do you know of a way to add that javascript to the URL that will enable it to run right when the website loads.

Comment: So you're essentially just trying to save time navigating the page? Why not simply manually navigate to the element in question? You can run JavaScript from the URL bar to have it run against the site you're currently on... just take it out of the `eventListener` and simply run the `.scrollTo()` method in the URL. Though honestly, it would probably be faster to manually navigate to the element than it would be to find those classes :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm trying to make a link that will take me to that position, so that if I click the link in 2 years from now (when I will forget where I wanted myself to scroll to) it should automatically take me there. So if you know how to add the url of the site plus the javascript in a single link, please tell me, cuz I can't seem to figure it out 